# Want to transfer amount from platform to connected account on stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripes

I want to transfer the amount to the connected account from the platform.

I have tried  [Transfer Api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers) But we have a limitation we can not send amounts outside of platform origin.

Now I want to transfer the amount with the help [destination charges api](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) but in this, we do not have any payment method because the customer is not involved in this process. In this API payment method is required to complete the transaction.

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => (int) $amount * 100,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'transfer_data' => [
                'destination' => {{connected_account_id}},
              ],
              'on_behalf_of' => {{connected_account_id}},
         ]);
```

Is any other way to transfer the amount to the connected account ??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming, but rather about how some off-site service works. Those questions should rather be asked to the service provider, which in this case is Stripe.

Comment: many users asked questions like this and get answers.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of people answering off-topic questions, it happens. But the vast majority of questions like this actually gets closed. A lot of people are doing a lot of things they shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I am here to get help from developers.

Comment: Then first contact Stripe and ask them what API/feature you should use. Once you have that and if you get stuck with your implementation (if you get stuck on something with your code, except from "what API to use or what data to send"), come back, post your attempt, add any error message and we can help from there. But first find out how the service actually works. That's your job to figure out. As far as we know, your issues/limits might be configurable from Stripe (which mean that we wouldn't be able to help, no matter how much we want to). I'm out...

Comment: I have contacted stripe support and gotten help about API but now I am facing an issue during the implementation of that API, therefore, I asked here if you can help you will be most welcome.

Comment: The [Transfer API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create) is your best option if a customer and payment isn’t involved in the process. You, the _platform_, can only transfer funds to a _connected account_ you’re associated with.